# How to create class attribute that is an alteration of the same class attribute

Tags: python, python-3.7

I have the following class:

```
@dataclass
class thing:
    DATE: datetime.datetime
    BEG_DATE: datetime.datetime = self.DATE.replace(day=1))
```

But I get this error:

> NameError("name 'DATE' is not defined")

Visual Studio points to line 4 where I'm trying to define BEG_DATE.

1) Why?

2) How can I create the attribute `BEG_DATE` that takes the `DATE` attribute and just changes the day to 1?

I've tried `field(default_factory=self.DATE.replace(day=1))`, but I got the same error.

Comment: @stovfl it is valid Python. Read up on [post-init processing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#post-init-processing)

Comment: @Joel: Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fields that depend on the values of other fields, you need to take advantage of [Post-init processing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#post-init-processing). The way you're doing it now, Python is trying to evaluate `self.DATE.replace(day=1)` when the class is created, rather than when the instance is created.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass
class thing:
    DATE: datetime.datetime
    BEG_DATE: datetime.datetime = field(init=False)

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.BEG_DATE = self.DATE.replace(day=1))
```